# jQuery autocomplete stops after 2nd letter entered

Tags: jquery, json, jquery-ui, jquery-autocomplete, jquery-ui-autocomplete

I've done some searching around but can't find an answer to my problem.

Problem: My implementation of jQuery autocomplete works when the first letter is typed into the input box however when the 2nd letter is typed in, the suggestion disappears (like I have entered an incorrect letter).

My jQuery code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
           $('#invite-connections').autocomplete({
               minLength: 0,
               source: <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>,
               focus: function(event, ui) {
                   $('#invite-connections').val(ui.item.name);
                   return false;
               },
               select: function(event, ui) {
                   $('#invite-connections').val(ui.item.name);
                   $('#invite-connections-user-id').val(ui.item.id);
                   $('#invite-connections-submit').show();
                   return false;
               }
           }) 
           .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
               return $("<li type=\"none\"></li>")
                    .data("item.autocomplete", item)
                    .append("<a><img src=\"" + item.pic + "\" /> " + item.name + "</a>")
                    .appendTo(ul);
           }
        });
        </script>
```

Here is the data that is passed to source (JSON encoded):

```
[{"name":"test 2","pic":"\/events\/images\/default\/dp\/micro_placeholder.jpg","id":"60705234"}]
```

So, when I type "t" it works, however when I type an "e" so "te" is now in the input box, the "test 2" suggestion disappears.

Anyone know what is going on here?

Thanks :)

Comment: @RicardoLohmann no error displayed, just stops providing a suggestion. Tried filling out the rest of the letters too, but nothing pops up

Answer (score 0):

The source array you use for autocomplete must have objects with a **`label`** property, a **`value`** property, or both (as outlined in the [overview page](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) in the documentation). You can transform your source array into one the widget supports by adding one of these properties:

```
var src = <?php echo json_encode($array); ?>;

$.each(src, function () {
    this.value = this.name;
});

$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#invite-connections').autocomplete({
        minLength: 0,
        source: src,
        focus: function(event, ui) {
            $('#invite-connections').val(ui.item.name);
            return false;
        },
        select : function(event, ui) {
            $('#invite-connections').val(ui.item.name);
            $('#invite-connections-user-id').val(ui.item.id);
            $('#invite-connections-submit').show();
            return false;
        }
    })
    .data("autocomplete")._renderItem = function(ul, item) {
        return $("<li type=\"none\"></li>")
            .data("item.autocomplete", item)
            .append("<a><img src=\"" + item.pic + "\" /> " + item.name + "</a>")
            .appendTo(ul);
    }
});​
```

**Example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ASwRj/

The reason that "t" and "e" were working is because the each object in your array's string representation looks something like:

```
[object Object]
```

Without any matching properties, the autocomplete widget attempted to match what you typed to the string representation of the object, which is why you stopped seeing the result the minute you typed "s."